# How to select random object from array with React Hooks?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, random, react-hooks

I don't know why my function not working. I won't to display random citites from array? But if I click button then show me

**Error -:**

```
AppHooks.js:15 Uncaught 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.`
```

What I do wrong?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


export default function AppHooks () {
    const [cities, setCities] = useState([
        {
            nameCity: 'Kraków'
        },
        {
            nameCity: "Kielce"
        }
    ])

    function randomCities (e, cities) {
        let len = cities.length;
        // let randCiti = cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length)];
        setCities(cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * len)]);
        return cities
    }
    let citi = cities.map((cit, i) => {
        return(
        <div key={i}>
            {cit.nameCity}
        </div>)
        }
    )

    console.log(cities[0]);
    return(
        <div>
            {citi}
            <button onClick={randomCities}> Change</button>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a random city from your array I would design the app different and just set the index to select from.

Also if you are using fat arrow functions there is no need to pass the cities to the click event-handler. I created a small example for you.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function AppHooks() {
  const cities = [
    {
      nameCity: "Kraków"
    },
    {
      nameCity: "Kielce"
    }
  ];

  const [activeCity, setActiveCity] = useState(0);

  const randomCities = e => {
    const len = cities.length;
    setActiveCity(Math.floor(Math.random() * len));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{cities[activeCity].nameCity}</div>
      <button onClick={randomCities}> Change</button>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<AppHooks />, rootElement);
```

[CodeSandbox - Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/l5l1lw2y5z?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thank you your answer was useful. https://github.com/Scherlock90/cities-changer/blob/master/src/AppHooks.js -->
this is my solution. now I have to make the child component inherit the same :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your onClick handler give to your method only one parameter - event.
So your cities is undefined here:

```
let len = cities.length;
```

If you want to pass another parametr with onClick you shoul use arrow function:

```
onClick={event => randomCities(event, cities)}
```

Comment: Thank you your answer was useful